# Transiting Turkey and getting visa for Indian passport holder?

Tags: indian-citizens, layovers, transit-visas, istanbul

In few months I would be flying from BOM - X - YUL (Montreal, Canada) . Now for X, one of the options is/was Istanbul Airport in part due to the free city tour they provide. But now I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43197/12-hour-stopover-in-istanbul-atat%C3%BCrk/) that you would need a visa to do that. I looked at the [FAQ](http://www.istanbulinhours.com/faq) , was able get to the link about [visas](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) but am confused by the double-speak. Could somebody explain what I should be doing -

> India: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their
>   travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service
>   passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary,
>   Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or
>   USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry
>   e-Visas valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided
>   that they meet certain conditions.

Now I don't have diplomatic passport holders nor would I be going to any of those other places. The e-visa link http://www.mfa.gov.tr/data/KONSOLOSLUK/e-visa-fees-en-31-december.pdf  doesn't mention Indians anywhere :(

Can somebody help or make sense of this gobbley-gook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not meet the requirements for a Turkish e-Visa.  You should instead apply for a visa sticker to be inserted in your passport before you begin your trip.

I found this information by following links from the website of the Turkish Consulate General in Mumbai: http://mumbai.bk.mfa.gov.tr/

The visa information page is at https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/VisaInfo/Index.

The first section includes a link to the page where you can begin the application process:

> ## Pre-Application System for Turkish Sticker Visa
>
> Beginning from 5 January 2016, all kinds of applications for Turkish visas will have to be made through the Pre-Application System of Turkish Sticker Visa ([www.visa.gov.tr](http://www.visa.gov.tr))
>
> Data required for visa applications will be uploaded to the system by the applicants. Following the online application, the applicants should apply to the Turkish Missions to complete the procedures including submission of their visa application forms duly signed and their passports as well as original copies of the application documents that have been already uploaded on the system.
>
> In countries where internet connection is weak or if the applicants experience difficulties in filling in the application form, applications can still be made directly to our relevant Turkish Missions.
>
> The applicants who meet the requirements will be directed by Pre-Application System for Turkish Sticker Visa to the e-Visa system ([www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr))
>
> An information note concerning the visa types granted by Turkey is available in the following address: ( http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa).